# How to install Pyqt5 on windows python

Tags: python, windows, installation, pyqt5, spyder

I am trying to install PyQt5 on my Windows 10 python 3.7. I tried several things suggested by different users like:

1. Install using pip install on cmd.
   pip not found error is showing.
2. Install PyQt5 from downloaded files.
   Not happening
3. Pip3 not working
4. Even my cmd is not recognizing that my pc has a python program on it.

Comment: Hello @Ankit  , your #4 I think you should set your python program path to your environment variables if you are on windows by the way.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you installed python and that you added it to a path?
when you type python in cmd what happens?
the following should appear when you type python in cmd :

```
Python 3.9.1 (tags/v3.9.1:1e5d33e, Dec  7 2020, 17:08:21) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

try to uninstall and install python if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest trying a few things, and then testing if you can use pip to install pyqt.

1. Try using pip3 instead of pip or vice versa
2. Try uninstalling and reinstalling python, making sure that you tick the box to add python to path
3. Restart your computer

If this doesn't work, then I don't know what else to do.